# Set default role for new user upon registration in genexus

Tags: genexus, genexus-gam

How can we set a default role for new user upon registration in genexus?

I have a registration page wherein a new user can create their account on their own. I want to set their default role on that registration process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the repository configuration you have this option:
[image]
It is the role that will be used by default for all users.

Another option is to subscribe to the new user event
and configure a procedure that adds the roles you need and eventually any other action you need at that time
This is a bit more advanced, you will find more details here

[GAM Events subscription](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?32698,GAM%20Events%20subscription)